# Is there any Alarm clock API?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to use an alarm clock in my application. Is there any API which provides the alarm clock and is close to Apple Alarm clock UI. I want to have UI similar to iOS default clock app. OR Do I have to create Alarm app on my own.

Comment: Create on your own

Comment: There are a lot of open source code about the clock in Github: https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&o=desc&q=Clock&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93